# Inner Join in laravel missing P

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, query-builder

I needed to combine the two table product_price and trade_channels, when I use inner join, 

the ID of product_price is remove.

Here is my code

```
DB::table('product_price')->where('product_id',$id)->where('action','customer_price')
         ->join('customers','product_price.action_id','=','customers.id')
         ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practise is to select a column that you actually want to use no need of all columns.

Suppose in this case you require all column of product_price table and only customer id from customer_price table then you can do something like this:

```
DB::table('product_price')
->select(['product_price.*','customer_price.id AS customer_id'])
->where('product_price.product_id',$id)
->where('product_price.action','customer_price')
->join('customers','product_price.action_id','=','customers.id')
->get();
```

You can select any column but it's good to take alias of join table column in this case it is customer_price so it's not getting confusion if both table has same name column.

Good Luck

Comment: Noted this has added a knowledge for me

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DB::table('product_price')
->select('*','product_price.id AS product_price_id')
->where('product_id',$id)
->where('action','customer_price')
->join('customers','product_price.action_id','=','customers.id')
->get();
```

the product_price id would be replace with customers id, so just print out the product_price id with other name.
hope it is help